# Deploy Django Telegram bot on digital ocean

Tags: python, django, python-telegram-bot

I am a beginner python programmer. I made a Telegram bot in Django framework. The bot's files are located in myapp/management/commands/bot.py. I am using 2 terminals on my computer to use both the bot and the Django administration on the local network. 1-terminal python manage.py bot. 2-terminal python manage.py runserver. I want to deploy this project in the digital ocean. What should I do for the Django administration and bot to work.Please help me!!!

Answer (score 0):

It's a little bit not an easy task to do, you are have to deploy your Django app, you can check this tutorial from digital ocean:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-20-04

then you are trying to create `systemd` or `service` or `deamon` to achieve what you did in the 2nd terminal